# Django create linked models using receiver or overwriting save?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Currently on my first advanced Django project and have what seems to be more of an architectural question. I have two models that represent an approval process and are related as follows:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Transaction(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class TransactionApproval(models.Model):
    ACTIONS = (
        (0, 'Declined'),
        (1, 'Approved'),
    )
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='approval_user')
    action = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ACTIONS, null=True, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
    def create_transaction_approval(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        """ Automatically adds approvers to the transaction when it's created. """
        if created:
            approvers = instance.requester.profile.get_manager()

            logger.info('[TRANSACTION] Adding managers {0} to approval list (UUID {1})'.format(str(approvers), instance.uid))
            for approver in approvers:
                TransactionApproval.objects.create(transaction=instance, user=approver)
```

Now I've been creating the TransactionApprovals automatically when a certain Transaction is created using `@receiver` as outlined above as approvals are a crucial and required part of Transactions. However I'm not sure if it actually doesn't make more sense move these actions to the already overwritten `def save()` method of Transactions, to avoid scattering logic and linking back and forth to models. Which of the two is architecturally cleverer and more standard-compliant?

```py
""" Alternative def save(): method of Transaction """

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info('[TRANSACTION] {0} created transaction (UUID {1})'.format(self.requester, self.uid))
        if not self.pk:
            super.save()
            approvers = self.requester.profile.get_manager()
            logger.info('[TRANSACTION] Adding managers {0} to approval list (UUID {1})'.format(str(approvers), instance.uid))
            for approver in approvers:
                TransactionApproval.objects.create(transaction=self, user=approver)
        else:
            super.save()
            # Other logic dealing with whether or not a transaction is fully approved
```

PS: Any other architectural leads are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid dealing with signals whenever I can. As cited on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) signals tend to duplicate themselves.

So, between the two I would choose overriding save method.

But as a better practice and to be more sure;

- Consider a case where you have already deployed the project, and on the production a problem occured, so you have to create a transaction_approval without automatically adding approvers.

Rather than automatically adding the approvers on model or db signal level, you should handle the issue on view level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So far I thought about just handling forms and authorization in the view logic, while keeping the application logic in the models. Just afraid I might oversee something if I handle Transaction variations in multiple views.